# How do I set breakpoints in JavaScript code that is inside the document?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I know how to use Chrome Developer tools to set breakpoints in JavaScript code, as long as the code is in a `.js` file.  However, if the code is inside a `<script>` tag inside an HTML document, I can't figure out how to find the code in developer tools in order to set the breakpoint.

Comment: have you tried adding a debugger in the script block?  For me I can see some of the code under the "Sources" tab, to the left there is a folder tree to choose from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the chrome developer tool and Navigate to the `Sources` and on the left side you see your `index.html` click on it and find the `<script>` tag and set you breakpoint.
[image]

Comment: I found my mistake... I had to drill down the folders of where my page was, then when I opened it, it was blank.  I then had to refresh the page to see the content, then find the script

Comment: Not your mistake, this is bad UX in the tools.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the HTML document in the sources tab of the developer tools and click the line number.

[image: screenshot of dev tools]

Comment: I don't see a script tab.  I just see Elements, Console, Sources, Network, Timeline, Profiles, Resources, Security and Audits

Comment: OK... I also needed to drill down the hierarchy to find the page, then open it (a blank pane opens), then refresh.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, you just set the breakpoint on the line number or use the `debugger;` statement directly in your Source Code.